# Como solucionar el error: "El proveedor 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' No esta registrado en el equipo local"

Tags: vb.net, odbc

Al momento de ejecutar un programa diseñado en **Visual Studio 2015 Community** muestra el siguiente error:

> El proveedor 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' No esta registrado en el equipo local

Ya instalé los drivers de 64 bits **(Windows 10 64 bits)** y aún sigue mostrando el mismo error.

¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Gracias.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar. Ahora no recupera los datos de la tabla

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Cierra tu Visual Studio.
2. Reinstala el driver, (puedes descargarlo [aquí](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=23734)).
3. Abre tu visual y haz tu conexión con Access.

Con eso ya debería funcionar.

**Si fuese el caso de que tu programa fue desarrollado en una maquina 32 bits o Access 2007**

1. Ve a propiedades del proyecto.
2. Haz clic en la sección de **Compile** (o compilación).
3. En donde dice **Target CPU**, cámbialo por x86.

Con eso también ya debería funcionar.

Saludos!

Comment: Lo estaba haciendo con los controladores de office 2010, con los que me recomendaste funciono, gracias.

Comment: El enlace marca 404...

Comment: @LucasD.A.W. fijate con este link:

https://www.microsoft.com/es-ar/download/details.aspx?id=13255