# Error al importar un archivo excel en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, excel, vb, oledb

Saludos a todos, resulta que estoy haciendo un importador que consiste en cargar datos de un archivo Excel a una tabla hecha en SQL Server (En una app hecha en VB.NET), estoy adaptando un código de acuerdo a mis necesidades y al importar el archivo Excel me manda el siguiente error

> El proveedor Microsoft ACE.OLEDB.12.0 no está registrado en el equipo local.

Cabe mencionar que en mi PC tengo instalado office 2016, el visual studio que uso es el VB 2010 Pro, no se si por ahí sea el motivo de mi error, agradezco mucho cualquier orientación que me puedan realizar.

```
Sub excelAsql()
    Dim myFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog()
    Dim xSheet As String = ""
    With myFileDialog
        .Filter = "Archivos de Excel |*.xlsx"
        .Title = "Abrir archivo excel"
        .ShowDialog()
    End With

    If myFileDialog.FileName.ToString <> "" Then
        Try
            Dim ExcelFile As String = myFileDialog.FileName.ToString
            xSheet = InputBox("Nombre de la Hoja", "")
            conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "data source=" & ExcelFile & "; " & "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes'")
            conn.Open()
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  [" & xSheet & "$]", conn)

            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            frmLista.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sería bueno que revises la pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24194/como-solucionar-error-el-proveedor-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-no-esta-registra

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió parte del hilo para solucionar mi problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado (basado en mi experiencia personal)!

con Instalar el siguiente Driver [Componentes de conectividad de datos](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=23734)

1. Después reiniciar Visual Studio
2. En el nombre del proyecto clic derecho y "Agregar referencia"
3. Clic en la pestaña COM y Seleccionar "Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library" y Listo!!