# problemas al importar archivo Excel en MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, importación

Tengo el siguiente codigo en el controller para importar datos de un archivo Excel:

```
public ActionResult importarExcel()
    {
        var retorno = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            var fileuploader = Request.Files[i];
            if (fileuploader.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string Foldername;
                string Extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileuploader.FileName);
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileuploader.FileName.ToString());
                if (Extension == ".XLS" || Extension == ".XLSX" || Extension == ".xls" || Extension == ".xlsx")
                {

                    Foldername = Server.MapPath("~/Importados/");

                    fileuploader.SaveAs(Foldername + filename.ToString());

                    String conStr = "";
                    switch (Extension)
                    {
                        case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                            conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                            "Data Source=" + Foldername + "//" + filename + ";" +
                            "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
                            break;

                        case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                            conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                           "Data Source=" + Foldername + "//" + filename + ";" +
                           "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
                            break;
                    }
                    OleDbConnection oconn = new OleDbConnection();
                    oconn.ConnectionString = conStr;

                    OleDbCommand ocmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", oconn);
                    oconn.Open();
                    OleDbDataReader odr = ocmd.ExecuteReader();
                    string partida = "";
                    string Description1 = "";
                    string Quantity1 = "";
                    string OriginalPrice1 = "";
                    string Image1 = "";
                    string Shape; string Carat; string Certificate;
                    while (odr.Read())
                    {
                        partida = valid(odr, 0);
                        Description1 = valid(odr, 1);
                        Quantity1 = valid(odr, 2);
                        OriginalPrice1 = valid(odr, 3);
                        Image1 = valid(odr, 4);
                        Shape = valid(odr, 5);
                        Carat = valid(odr, 6);
                        Certificate = valid(odr, 7);

                        // you will get row by value
                    }

                }

            }
        }
        return Json(retorno);
    }

   protected string valid(OleDbDataReader myreader, int stval)//if any columns are found null then they are replaced by zero
    {
        object val = myreader[stval];
        if (val != DBNull.Value)
            return val.ToString();
        else
            return Convert.ToString(0);
    }
```

Pero resulta que cuando trato de abrir la conexión en la linea oconn.Open() después del OleDbCommand, me sale el siguiente error:

**El proveedor 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' no está registrado en el equipo local.**

El archivo que trato de importar en un archivo excel del office 2016.

Si alguien sabe algo, se le agradece su ayuda.
Desde ya, gracias.

Comment: Hay algunas preguntas similares publicadas, has intentado con alguna ? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24194/como-solucionar-error-el-proveedor-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-no-esta-registra

Comment: Quizá sea lo que buscas, trata de guiarte con este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awwI1AJIBag

Comment: Pero que tiene que ver access, o conectarse con un archivo acces si yo estoy importando un archivo excel. Deseo leer los datos de las columnas del archivo excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo tienes un problema con los drivers de tu pc intenta descargando esto:

> https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=23734

Pruebas a ver que tal y me comentas.