# El proveedor Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 no está registrado office 2016 no puedo solucionar

Tags: base-de-datos, vb.net, visual-studio

hola tengo instalado Acces2016 y visual studio 2012. me aparece ese error y con la instalacion del AccessDatabaseEngine_X64 no lo puedo solucionar. Alguno tuvo el mismo problema? Como lo Soluciono?

Comment: Hola Andres. Conteste esta pregunta hace unos cuantos años atras. Me imagino que la solucion es la misma. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24194/como-solucionar-error-el-proveedor-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-no-esta-registra/24236#24236

Comment: hola twoDent si vi la respuesta anterior pero no me funciono. puede ser porque es acces 2016 y visual 2012?.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución, antes no me había funcionado. Cambié la compilación a x64 y funcionó. No sé si fue el reinicio o qué, pero funcionó.
Gracias